PICe Gen 5 AIC dropped to Gen4 after loopback?
Before loopback the board has completed link traning and stable at L0. After setting the loopback inside the AIC chip toward the RC, the link downgraded to Gen 4!
What could possbily caused such an issue? The Firmware should be all right. This leaves the suspects to be chip or pkg design. Any idea?
